# Bootstrapping of pairs in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, random, statistics-bootstrap

I would like to extend "univariate bootstrapping" to "multivariate bootsrapping", meaning in a first step I draw randomly with replacement out of a one-dimensional vector using this code:

```
s = RandStream.getGlobalStream();
reset(s)

n = 100000;                  % # of independent random trials
h = 52;                     % horizon
T = size(Resid_standard, 1);

Resid_bootstrapped = Resid_standard(unidrnd(T, h, n));
```

Now, the basic vector Resid_standard is not a uni-dimensional vector but a Tx2 matrix and I want to not only draw random numbers but random pairs.

- How do I have to modify my code to achieve this?
- The output in the univariate case is a 100000x50 matrix. The output for the two-dimensional case would be three-dimensional. How could I store my results?

Comment: You might want to ret-ag the question as [tag:statistics-bootstrap], if appropriate (I'd do it myself but I'm unfamiliar with the topic of your question, and so I'm not sure it's correct).

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to store the index vector, make use of linear indexing, and concatenate the results:

```
r_ind = unidrnd(T, h, n);
Resid_bootstrapped = cat(3, Resid_standard(r_ind), Resid_standard(r_ind + T));
```

`Resid_bootstrapped` will then be a `h`×`n`×2 matrix.

This can even be shortened into a one-liner:

```
Resid_bootstrapped = reshape(Resid_standard(unidrnd(T, h, n), [1,2]), h, n, 2);
```